# Add CRL (certificate revocating list) url to certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, client-certificates, certificate-revocation

I am generating the root CA using the commands below:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca.key.pem -passout pass:KeyPassword 4096
openssl req -key ca.key.pem -passin pass:Password -new -x509 -days 365 -sha256 -out ca.root.pem
```

and then I'm creating signed user certificates (without using intermediate certificates) using the commands below:

1) Generate a key for user

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout keyname.pem -days 365
```

2) Create a CSR

```
openssl req -out keyname.csr -key keyname.pem -new -days 365
```

3) Signing the key with root cert

```
openssl ca -batch -create_serial -config openssl.cnf -cert ca.root.pem -keyfile ca.key.pem -passin pass:KeyFinalPassword -in keyname.csr -out certname.pem
```

4) Generate .p12 file

```
openssl pkcs12 -name username -inkey keyname.pem -in certname.pem -export -out username.p12 -password pass:password
```

Note - I've added crlDistributionPoints = URI:http://localhost:8000/crl/distripoint.crl.pem to the openssl.cnf along with below options:

```
# For certificate revocation lists.
# crlDistributionPoints = URI:http://HOSTNAME/crl/distripoint.crl.pem
crlDistributionPoints = URI:http://localhost:8000/crl/distripoint.crl.pem
crlnumber         = $dir/config/crl/crlnumber
crl               = $dir/config/crl/ca.crl.pem
crl_extensions    = crl_ext
default_crl_days  = 60
```

Note- I generated distribution.crl.pem using [this tutorial](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/certificate-revocation-lists.html)

Answer (score 5):

The `crlDistributionPoints` parameter must be added to the `x509_extensions` section of the CA you are using. (In your example, it looks like you have added this parameter to the CA section itself.)

`openssl ca` using the `openssl.cnf` with these lines adds the `CRL Distribution Points` extension to the issued certificate:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca      = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
(...other parameters...)
x509_extensions = added-extensions

[ added-extensions ]
crlDistributionPoints = URI:http://localhost:8000/crl/distripoint.crl.pem
```

You might want to use a custom `openssl.cnf` instead of the default one for `req` and `ca` commands; the default contains many example entries which may not do what you want. Here are [examples of minimal `openssl.cnf`](http://technotes.shemyak.com/posts/min-openssl-cnf/).

(Side note: your last command generating .p12 file is not relevant to the question; it only packs already created certificates in another format.)